# Unit testing Java class with Mockito mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I wrote 2 classes in Java. These are `Developer` and `GroupManager`. Developer has field `private GroupManager supervisor` (with getter and setter) describing who hires him. What is more, `GroupManager` has following method:

```
public class GroupManager {

    //...

    private List<Developer> employees;

    public void hire(Developer e) {
        if(canHire()) {
            if(employees.contains(e)) {
                System.out.println(e.getName() + " is already hired");
            }
            else {
                e.setSupervisor(this);
                employees.add(e);
                System.out.println(getName() + " is now hiring " + e.getName());
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(getName() + "cannot hire more employees.");
        }
    }

}
```

This class exposes method `hire` which set supervisor on given developer.
I would like to write tests for class `Developer`.
I did it like this:

```
@Test
public void hiringWorksAsItShould() throws Exception {
    GroupManager gm = new GroupManager("John Doe", "manager", 1);
    gm.hire(developer);
    assertThat(developer.getSupervisor()).isInstanceOf(GroupManager.class);
}
```

I am using FEST testing framework but since it is very intuitive I belive everyone can understand what it means. This test passes, but because I want it to be unit test a decided to replace `= new GroupManager` with `= mock(GroupManager.class)`. The problem is that now this test fails. How could I correct this Mockito feature to check is developer's supervisor is instance of `GroupManager`.

EDIT 
The error I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expecting actual value not to be null
    at org.fest.assertions.Fail.failure(Fail.java:228)
    at org.fest.assertions.Fail.fail(Fail.java:167)
    at org.fest.assertions.Fail.failIfActualIsNull(Fail.java:100)
    at org.fest.assertions.GenericAssert.isNotNull(GenericAssert.java:238)
    at org.fest.assertions.ObjectAssert.isInstanceOf(ObjectAssert.java:52)
    at DeveloperTest.hiringWorksAsItShould(DeveloperTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

The Developer class:

```
public class Developer {
    private final String name;
    private String role;
    private Manager supervisor;


    public Manager getSupervisor() {
        return supervisor;
    }

    public void setSupervisor(Manager supervisor) {
        this.supervisor = supervisor;
    }
}
```

The DeveloperTest class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class DeveloperTest {

    static final Developer developer = new Developer("John Doe", "developer");



    @Test
    public void hiringWorksAsItShould() throws Exception {
        GroupManager gm = mock(GroupManager.class);
        gm.hire(developer);
        assertThat(developer.getSupervisor()).isInstanceOf(GroupManager.class);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the test fail when you mock it out?

Comment: I've just edited my question with it.

Comment: And why are you using "isInstanceOf"? I would expect that the GroupManager object that is returned by getSuperviser() after hiring ... should be equal to the one you called "hire()" on. Just checking if the object is of a certain class; doesn't really buy you much.

Comment: Yep, it's exactly what I am doing. But it is for educational purposes and I would be very grateful if I know why it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to replace the GroupManager with a mock and not the employee?

If you have...

```
@Test
public void hiringWorksAsItShould() throws Exception {
    GroupManager gm = mock(GroupManager.class);

    gm.hire(developer); // YOU ARE CALLING THE MOCK HERE THEN!!
    assertThat(developer.getSupervisor()).isInstanceOf(GroupManager.class);
}
```

Don't you want something like this instead?

```
@Test
public void hiringWorksAsItShould() throws Exception {
    // CLASS UNDER TEST   \/
    GroupManager gm = new GroupManager("John Doe", "manager", 1);

    // Mock "developer"...
    Developer developer = mock(Developer.class);

    gm.hire(developer); 

    verify(developer).setSupervisor(gm);        
}
```

So as you are testing the GroupManager, this should be a solid implementation and things that react with it (i.e. the Developer) should be mocked.

Comment: But my code is testing Developer class and yours GroupManager.

Comment: @onegrx - could you post the source code for the class / method you are actually trying to test then? (If you replace GroupManager with a mock as suggested in the first post, then you are not actually testing anything!)

Comment: @onegrx If you put a breakpoint on the "gm.hire(developer)" method and step into it, you will see that you end up somewhere in Mockito's code. Your code to do the hiring will never actually get called which is why the value is "null" in the assertion. Looking at your employee class, there really isn't much to test apart from "an employee should store it's supervisor". If this is a unit test for Employee, then I am not sure what "GroupManager" should have to do with anything

Comment: So you say that this feature is connected to GroupManagerTest more than DeveloperTest?

Comment: @onegrx yes, that's where the logic is